Monolog JsonFormatter one-level array of same-structured objects
I'm trying to get a JSON output from monolog that's a one level array with the different logged items, like this (when formatted):
[
  {
    "message": "test",
    "context": {},
    "level": 500,
    "level_name": "CRITICAL",
    "channel": "APP",
    "datetime": "2024-06-16T08:31:26.931574-04:00",
    "extra": {}
  },
  {
    "message": "test",
    "context": {},
    "level": 500,
    "level_name": "CRITICAL",
    "channel": "APP",
    "datetime": "2024-06-16T08:31:27.094920-04:00",
    "extra": {}
  }
]

I've searched around stackoverflow but haven't found a solution yet for this type of output. I saw that you can have monolog pretty print the JSON but that's not what I was looking for, I simply want it to append future logs to the end of the already created array.
I assume Monolog itself would have to realize that there's previous logs and then prepend the comma before adding the new entry
Is this not possible in Monolog?
My handler code:
        $handler = new StreamHandler( MY_PATH . '/logs/app.json' );
        $handler->setFormatter( new JsonFormatter() );
        $logger->pushHandler( $handler );

Using monolog 2.9
